# Get div id's of all divs with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get `div` `id`s of all `div` elements having a specific `CSS` class.
I am able to get `[object HTMLDivElement]` by `using getElementByClass` but I haven't been able to get `id` from this object.
Basically, entirely I want to do is

- get `div` `id`s of all `div` elements that have a specific `CSS` class,
- get `data-title` of all `div` elements,
- match `data-title` of these `div` elements with a string,
- make `display:none` of all non-matching `div` elements.

Here is what I have tried:

```
function FilterFiles(filterItem) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

        alert(elements[i].id); 
        //  get div id of divs with data-title !=(not equal) filterItem
        // make display:none of matching divs
    }
}
```

Here is the Fiddle with actual `HTML` http://jsfiddle.net/6bo1rjrt/1/.

Comment: there are no `id` attributes in teh `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var  temp = new Array(); 
var  title = new Array();   

function FilterFiles(filterItem) {

           $('.listItem').each(function () 
            {
                temp.push($(this).attr("id")); //get id of each div to array
                alert($(this).attr("id"));

                title.push($(this).attr("data-title")); //get title of each div to array

                 if($(this).attr("data-title") != filterItem) //check non matching div
                 {
                    $(this).hide(); //hide div
                 }

            });


    }
```

first u loop throught all div with specific class with each, then check it's "data-title".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attribute-not-equal-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector) for that. also you need to give ids to div elements:

```
function FilterFiles(filterItem) {
  var ids= $('.listItem[data-title!="'+filterItem+'"]').map(function(){
       return this.id;
   }).get()
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/092yhj98/)**

For hiding elements that do not have data-title value equal to:

```
$('.listItem[data-title!="'+filterItem+'"]').hide()
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can do it without div ids?  Actually this html is randomly generated from client. can I filter divs by matching their data-title with a string and make css diplnay:none of aa non matching divs?

Comment: You can use `$('.listItem[data-title!="'+filterItem+'"]').hide()`. filterItem should be data-title string value.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery, you can do the following:

```
var arr = [];
$('.listItem').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery `.each()`:**

```
var arr = [];
$('.listItem').each(function(){
  arr.push(this.id);
});
```

**Using jQuery `.map()`**

```
var arr = $('.listItem').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your fiddle example. see this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bo1rjrt/1/)

```
$("#filter").click(function () {
    var filterItem = "A03-5(KAB製ﾋｰﾀｰ付ｴｱｻｽｵﾍﾟｼｰﾄ)_20140515154904.xlsx";
    FilterFiles(filterItem);
});

function FilterFiles(filterItem) {
    var elements = $("div.listItem");
    elements.each(function(){
        var el=$(this);
        if(el.data("title")!=filterItem)
            el.hide();
        else
            el.show();
    });


    /*for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

        alert(elements[i].id);
        //  get div id of divs with data-title !=(not equal) filterItem
        // make display:none of matching divs
    }*/
}
```